# netty-socketio server, how to handler socket.io client authentification request?

Tags: java, socket.io, netty

i use netty-socketio 1.6.6 and netty-socketio-demo from github.com

```
var socket =  io.connect('http://192.168.202.13:9092', {'username': 'ron', 'password': '1111'});
```

when i send message, i could find it in

```
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO com.corundumstudio.socketio.handler.PacketHandler - In message: 5:::{"name":"chatevent","args":[{"userName":"user470","message":"ssssssssss"}]} sessionId: 9c6f22f4-7d19-4632-ba50-4eb70b845a13
```

but when connectting, i cannot find `'username': 'guo', 'password': '1111'` in
`[nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO com.corundumstudio.socketio.handler.PacketHandler - In message: 2:: sessionId: 9c6f22f4-7d19-4632-ba50-4eb70b845a13`.

What i want to do is

1.authentification.

2.send message to one particular user.

Thanks for any help.

By now, no answer. Slowly I realize i put username and password on the wrong place.
I need write an anthentification event to fulfil this request.
Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

The authentification data in socketio sends via connection params, like:

```
http://192.168.202.13:9092/socketio/1/?username=ron&password=1111
```

In your netty-socketio `Configuration` object define follow param:

```
    config.setAuthorizationListener(new AuthorizationListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean isAuthorized(HandshakeData data) {
            String username = data.getSingleUrlParam("username");
            String password = data.getSingleUrlParam("password");
            // if username and password correct
               return true;
            // else
               return false;
        }
    });
```